# How to configure android for not turn on the screen at the time of charging connection/disconnetion?

Tags: screen, backlight

I want to android device not turn on screen when I connect it to charge and when disconnect from charge.
How and where it may configure?

Comment: Is your device roorted? I am not aware of a way to do so on an unrooted device. On a rooted device with xposed I heard that it is possible to disable using the Xposed module "Gravity box". Also on certain custom roms the auto screen-on when charging starts/stops can be configured.

Comment: Which Android device are you using? Some OEMs give this option under settings (sometimes under Developer Settings).

Comment: @Robert device is not rooted

Comment: @Firelord OS is Android One 9